# Inset UITextField, with different values for left and right

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to do a clone of Instagram and I little bit stuck with a UITextField customization. Maybe is a noob question but here it goes.

What I'm trying to achieve if to have different inset for my UITextField, one smaller on the left side and one bigger on the right side, so I have space enough for the clear button from UITextField.

I'm trying to achieve this:
[Instagram app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQPpc.png)

but the closest thing I get is this:
[Clone app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC9MC.png)

As you can see the clear button is much more squeeze on my version, but I can't handle to inset only the right side a little bit more, without touching the left one.

I used the following code on my UITextField subclass (Swift 3):

```
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 16, dy: 0)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 16, dy: 0)
    }
```

But it only let me do it for booth side changing dx. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by myself:

```
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 16, dy: 0)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 16, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width - 56, height: bounds.height)
    }

    override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.width - 36, y: bounds.origin.y, width: 16, height: bounds.height)
    }
```

This way it work just like Instagram. It inset a little bit more the right side when is in editing mode, and when is in normal mode it has a inset of 16 both side.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16))
textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
textField.rightView = rightView

let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
textField.leftView = leftView
```

May it helps you.

Comment: I also tried this, but the problem with this approach is that, at least in Swift 3, the clear button disappear when you use the rightView... Anyway I found a way to do so